# How to modify a single value in JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using Google Play Games Snapshot and I have to pass in the data I need to save by using JSON.

Here is the JSON file:

```
{"Date":1531043635316,"Daily bonus":2,"sound enabled":true,"total coins":2099300,"high score":0,"Btns Set":1,"leftBtnX":46,"leftBtnY":18,"leftBtnsize":1,"upBtnX":105,"upBtnY":18,"upBtnsize":1,"rightBtnX":164,"rightBtnY":18,"rightBtnsize":1,"guardBtnX":288,"guardBtnY":18,"guardBtnsize":1,"chargeBtnX":363,"chargeBtnY":18,"chargeBtnsize":1,"attackBtnX":438,"attackBtnY":18,"attackBtnsize":1,"superBtnX":438,"superBtnY":58,"superBtnsize":1,"ultimateBtnX":363,"ultimateBtnY":58,"ultimateBtnsize":1,"dpadX":80,"dpadY":40,"dpadSize":1,"gpadX":405,"gpadY":59,"gpadSize":1}
```

Now when I try to change only one of them using this code:

```
private byte[] saveToJSON(){
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("total coins", Settings.totalCoins);
        return obj.toString().getBytes();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Error converting save data to JSON.", e);
    }
}
```

The entire file get's changed to only this single parameter, it becomes this:

```
{"total coins":2099300}
```

Now how Can I just modify a single parameter value?

Sorry, this is the first time for me to work with JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();` make you create a new json object,that's the reason,you can change to below code:

```
String jsonStr = "";//your json string
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
obj.put("total coins", Settings.totalCoins);
```